# Save audit for an entity using nestjs and typeorm

Tags: javascript, nestjs, typeorm

I have an entity `Audit` Like below in Nestjs app with typeorm for mongodb:

```
@Entity()
export class Audit {

  @Column()
  createdBy: string;

  @BeforeInsert()
  setAudit() {
    this.createdBy = ???
  }
}

@Entity()
export class Post extends Audit {

  @Column()
  title: string;

  ...
}
```

My other entities extend `Audit` and in my application i'm using jwt to authenticate users.

The problem is that when i want to save an entity i don't know how to set createdBy with @BeforeInsert hook...

I know we have user in request but i don't know what is the correct way of bringing user into `setAudit` method?

Answer (score 6):

I would like to share my solution regarding this issue.
Since [EventSubscribers can't be request scoped](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database#subscribers) you have to use [some kind of storage](https://github.com/Papooch/nestjs-cls) to store the user information coming from the request. This module can help you separate context for every single request. The problem with other implementation I tried was that my scope was global, so other requests could overwrite the user, while the original request was handled. I could have thought that...

Base entity with audit columns (other entities will extend this class):

```
export class BaseEntity extends DateEntity {
  @Column({ nullable: false })
  createdBy: string;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  updatedBy: string;
}
```

Interceptor (this is where you can set your user information):

```
@Injectable()
export class UserInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  constructor(private readonly cls: ClsService) {}

  intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<any> {
    const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    const user = request.user;
    this.cls.set('user', user?.username);
    return next.handle();
  }
}
```

EventSubscriber (this will listen to every insert and update event for the entities extended from BaseEntity):

```
@EventSubscriber()
export class UserSubscriber implements EntitySubscriberInterface<BaseEntity> {
  constructor(dataSource: DataSource, private readonly cls: ClsService) {
    dataSource.subscribers.push(this);
  }
  listenTo() {
    return BaseEntity;
  }
  beforeInsert(event: InsertEvent<BaseEntity>) {
    event.entity.createdBy = this.cls.get('user');
  }

  beforeUpdate(event: UpdateEvent<BaseEntity>) {
    event.entity.updatedBy = this.cls.get('user');
  }
}
```

Register the subscriber and the interceptor as a provider in your app.module globally (or use it with @UseInterceptor():

```
providers: [
UserSubscriber,
    {
      provide: APP_INTERCEPTOR,
      useClass: UserInterceptor,
    },
],
```

Also you have to import the ClsModule for your app:

```
ClsModule.forRoot({
      global: true,
      middleware: { mount: true },
    }),
```

I hope this will help. For further information please see the docs.

Comment: After hours struggling with DataSource injection at Subscriber, I found that I had to annotate it with @InjectDataSource(). Maybe it's something related to Nestjs v9.0.0.

Answer (score 2):

You can't access the request directly from inside a TypeORM entity, as they are in separate contexts. You could, instead, fill the createdBy field through a service.

```js
@Injectable()
class DataService {
// ...

   async create({ request, user }): Promise<any> {
    await this.repository.create({...request.body, createdBy: user.id });
   }

// ...
}
```

Another solution would be creating a common service that can work for every entity, and inside that service you could fill the createdBy property.

```js
/*
 * DataService
 ? Service to be able to fetch any kind of TypeORM entity from the controllers
 ? or another services.
*/
@Injectable()
export class DataService {
    
    /*
     * _.getRepository
     ? Method to get a repository by having only the type of an entity.
     * @param type The type of the entity
     * @returns a repository of the specified entity.
    */
    private getRepository<T>(type: new () => T) {
        return getRepository(type)
    }
    
    /*
     * _.save
     ? A method to save an entity regarding its entity type.
     * @param type the type of the entity
     * @param model the model to save. It should have an ID.
     * @param user the user creating this entity
     * @returns a DeepPartial object representing the edited or created object.
    */
    public save<T extends Audit>(type: new () => T, model: DeepPartial<T>, user: User): Promise<DeepPartial<T> & T> {
        const repository: Repository<T> = this.getRepository(type);
        return repository.save({...model, createdBy: user.id});
    }

   
}
```

Then, you will be able to do something like this...

```js
// ... 

@Post('create')
@UseInterceptor(FillUser)
public async create(@Body() body:any, @Req() request:any) {
  const { user } = request.session.user // <--- Just for example. 
  return await this.service.create(Post, body, user)
}

// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I followed a lot of threads on this particular problem. For me, the issue is that the application uses URL versioning combined with REQUEST-scoped database connections.

My goal was to capture the authorized user id into a SESSION variable at the start of each transaction. The application has a trigger operation that captures the before/after images of row-level changes. By referencing that SESSION variable in the trigger, it would become possible to record what user made the change, without having to modify existing tables to include that property for capture. Even if the row was modified to include that metadata, there is no provision to capture the user id in the DELETE event.

Since REQUEST-scoped injection cannot be mixed with TypeORM EventSubscribers, not a lot of the existing docs was very promising. I followed [Masterchief](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13127685/masterchief) example above and got pretty far.

Ultimately, I came to the conclusion that I needed to register the EventSubscriber *twice*.

In the first instantiation, by way of the app global module, the EventSubscriber gets access to the properly DI-injected ClsService.

But, because the connection is REQUEST-scoped, there is no datasource passed to the EventSubscriber to subscribe to.

To overcome that, the EventSubscriber is *also* present in the TypeORM config to inject it as a subscriber.

The second instantiation comes from the TypeORM code.

As a result, both Nestjs and TypeORM instantiate the EventSubscriber, but through a simple hack, we return the *first* instance to TypeORM, giving it the properly DI-injected, REQUEST-scoped EventSubscriber.

```js
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ClsService } from 'nestjs-cls';
import { EntitySubscriberInterface, EventSubscriber, TransactionStartEvent } from 'typeorm';
import { BaseEntity } from '../../../base.entity';

let instance: UserIdSubscriber;

@EventSubscriber()
@Injectable()
export class UserIdSubscriber implements EntitySubscriberInterface<BaseEntity> {
  constructor(@Inject(ClsService) public cls: ClsService) {
    instance ||= this;
    return instance;
  }

  async beforeTransactionStart(event: TransactionStartEvent): Promise<void> {
    await event.queryRunner.query(
      `SET SESSION auditing_trigger_parameters.user_id = ${this.cls.get('userId')}`,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I followed your and @Masterchief examples.
However, I am getting this.cls as undefined in the Subscriber class. Is there anything I am missing? Thanks

Comment: I also answered a similar question in more detail here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64343930/nestjs-not-getting-injectable-to-work-on-subscriber/76203354#76203354 maybe that will help!