# NestJs - not getting Injectable to work on subscriber

Tags: nestjs

Using a subscriber (db based on TypeORM) I could not find how to get access to the request (to get auth user creating the booking over Rest api)

I tried using Injectable as described in [doc](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/injection-scopes) but doesn't seem to work here.

Thanks for help

booking.subscriber.ts

```js
import { Inject, Injectable, Scope } from '@nestjs/common';
import { throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { Account } from 'src/accounts';
import { Room } from 'src/rooms';
import { TransactionEntity, TransactionsModule } from 'src/transactions';
import {
  EventSubscriber,
  EntitySubscriberInterface,
  InsertEvent,
  getRepository,
  LessThan,
  MoreThan,
} from 'typeorm';
import { Booking } from './booking.entity';
import { REQUEST } from '@nestjs/core';
import { Request } from 'express';

@EventSubscriber()
@Injectable({ scope: Scope.REQUEST })
export class BookingsSubscriber implements EntitySubscriberInterface<Booking> {
  constructor(@Inject(REQUEST) private request: Request) {
    console.log('request', this.request) // return undefined
  }

  listenTo() {
    return Booking;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

As noted in the documentation, [Event Subscribers cannot be request scoped](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database#subscribers). What you're trying to do isn't doable in Nest due to TypeORM and Nest having different container systems to hold metadata.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up adding the user to the request.body in an interceptor.

Comment: @AntonyGibbs can you elaborate on that? I am currently having the same issue. I would like to get the current user of the request into a subscriber. Thanks!

Comment: @mangei I found the interceptor... It's an old abandoned project.  Posted an answer with the `Interceptor`

Answer (score 1):

this is what I use... I was nestjs newbee and my management of user auth has very much changed since and I would recommend to reconsider the logic.

```js
import {
  CallHandler,
  ExecutionContext,
  Injectable,
  NestInterceptor,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class BookingsInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<any> {
    const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();

    if (request.body) {
      request.body.user = request.user;
    }

    return next.handle();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a simple workaround for this problem. The NestJS application can have an `EventSubscriber` that is `Injectable` and request-scoped. The trick is managing the two different DI systems in use by NestJS and TypeORM.

The solution I needed was the simplest one that seemed very difficult to manage: audit all changes to the database, along with the user id that made the change.

To achieve this goal, I first needed to capture the logged in user id. The user object in the HTTP request contains the logged in identity. So, a `NestInterceptor` is used to intercept the HTTP request and store the `userId` in the `ClsService` context. This allows the application to store a request-scoped parameter for later consumption.

```js
@Injectable()
export class UserIdInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  constructor(@Inject(ClsService) public cls: ClsService) {}

  intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<any> {
    const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    this.cls.set('userId', request.user?.id);
    return next.handle();
  }
}
```

Next, create the `EventSubscriber` like a normal injectable service and inject the `ClsService` from the `nestjs-cls` npm module.

Setup the hook to capture the changes before the transaction begins. In the `beforeTransactionStart` hook, use Postgres `SET SESSION` command to store a session-scoped parameter `user_id`. This needs to be prefixed with some namespace e.g. `auditing_trigger_parameters.` (notice the `.` in the prefix).

```js
let instance: UserIdSubscriber;

@EventSubscriber()
@Injectable()
export class UserIdSubscriber implements EntitySubscriberInterface<BaseEntity> {
  constructor(@Inject(ClsService) public cls: ClsService) {
    // this hack is done to overcome the limitation that REQUEST-scoped DI doesn't work w/ TypeORM subscribers
    // the first instantiation happens by Nestjs while creating the app (w/ DI)
    // the second instantiation happens by TypeORM while registering the Subscriber (w/o DI)
    instance ||= this;
    return instance;
  }

  async beforeTransactionStart(event: TransactionStartEvent): Promise<void> {
    await event.queryRunner.query(
      `SET SESSION auditing_trigger_parameters.user_id = ${this.cls.get('userId')}`,
    );
  }
}
```

Inside a trigger function the BEFORE/AFTER image of the change is captured in the audit table. This trigger function can access the session-scoped parameter.

```sql
      CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION auditing_trigger ()
        RETURNS TRIGGER

        AS $BODY$

          DECLARE user_id TEXT;
          DECLARE before_image JSONB;
          DECLARE after_image JSONB;

          BEGIN

            SELECT current_setting('auditing_trigger_parameters.user_id', true)
            INTO user_id;

            IF user_id !~ '\\d+' THEN
              user_id = NULL;
            END IF;

            CASE TG_OP
              WHEN 'INSERT' THEN
                after_image = TO_JSONB(NEW);
              WHEN 'DELETE' THEN
                before_image = TO_JSONB(OLD);
              WHEN 'UPDATE' THEN
                before_image = TO_JSONB(OLD);
                after_image = TO_JSONB(NEW);
            END CASE;

            INSERT INTO audit_logs (
              "userId",
              "operation",
              "tableName",
              "beforeImage",
              "afterImage"
            )

            VALUES (
              user_id::integer,
              TG_OP,
              TG_TABLE_NAME,
              before_image,
              after_image
            );

            RETURN NULL;

          END;

        $BODY$

        LANGUAGE PLpgSQL;
```

This trigger function is generic so it can be attached to all the application tables.

```sql
      CREATE TRIGGER foo_audit_trigger
        AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE
        ON foo
        FOR EACH ROW
        EXECUTE PROCEDURE auditing_trigger ();
```

So the last step is getting all this to play nicely together. For this to work both NestJS and TypeORM need to perform their DI functions but the run-time application will use the request-scoped values.

Register the NestJS Interceptor and the TypeORM EventSubscriber as top-level providers for the application. Also, import the global ClsModule.

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
    ClsModule.forRoot({ global: true, middleware: { mount: true } }),
    // ... more imports
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_INTERCEPTOR,
      useClass: UserIdInterceptor,
    },
    UserIdSubscriber,
    // ... more providers
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Finally, in addition to the registration for the NestJS application, register the EventSubscriber with the TypeORM configuration.

```js
export default registerAs('typeORM', () => ({
  type: 'postgres',
  subscribers: [UserIdSubscriber],
  // ... more props
}));
```

Going back to the EventSubscriber, notice the comment in the constructor. The constructor always returns the *first* instance.

The NestJS application registers the EventSubscriber first, properly performing DI injection of the ClsService. The instance is captured in the function scope.

The TypeORM subscriber then registers the EventSubscriber again, but it receives the original instance, which was properly constructed by NestJS.

At run-time, the request-based event is passed before the transaction starts, and this event has a queryRunner that is specific for the request itself. Here, the application stores the session parameter previously captured by the ClsService upstream in the NestInterceptor.

Finally, the database trigger can retrieve this session parameter and store this value alongside the before and after image and other auditing parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested the library [nj-request-scope](https://github.com/kugacz/nj-request-scope) and it seems to work well.

With that library the implementation would be something like the follow:

```js
import { Inject, Scope } from '@nestjs/common';
import { throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { Account } from 'src/accounts';
import { Room } from 'src/rooms';
import { TransactionEntity, TransactionsModule } from 'src/transactions';
import {
  EventSubscriber,
  EntitySubscriberInterface,
  InsertEvent,
  getRepository,
  LessThan,
  MoreThan,
} from 'typeorm';
import { Booking } from './booking.entity';
import { REQUEST } from '@nestjs/core';
import { Request } from 'express';

@EventSubscriber()
export class BookingsSubscriber implements EntitySubscriberInterface<Booking> {
  constructor(@Inject(NJRS_REQUEST) private request: Request) { // request is singleton
    console.log('request', this.request) // return the request properly
  }

  listenTo() {
    return Booking;
  }
}
```