# How to get request object inside the entity class in nestJs

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I'm working on a small project in nestJs,
I need to add audit columns for some entities.
For that I'm setting user information on a request object, I'm sure that it is setting correctly.
And Saw working fine if I print request object in controller .
But this not working on entity classes.

I'm trying like this :

```
import { Req } from "@nestjs/common";
import { Exclude } from "class-transformer";
import { BeforeInsert, BeforeUpdate, Column, CreateDateColumn, DeleteDateColumn, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, UpdateDateColumn } from "typeorm";

export class BaseModel{
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
    id:string

    @CreateDateColumn()
    created_at:Date

    @Column({default:null})
    created_by:string

    @UpdateDateColumn()
    modified_at:Date

    @Column({default:null})
    modified_by:string

    @DeleteDateColumn({select:false})
    @Exclude()
    deleted_at:Date

    @BeforeInsert()
    setAuditsBeforeInsert(@Req() req:any){
        this.created_by=req.currentUser.id;
        this.modified_by=req.currentUser.id;
    }

    @BeforeUpdate()
    setAuditsBeforeUpdate(@Req() req:any){
        this.modified_by=req.currentUser.id;
    }
}
```

here in @BeforeInsert() and @BeforeUpdate() hooks, request object is coming as undefined.
Can any one help me please?
If this is not a right way please tell me how can I set createdBy and modifiedBy columns with userId.

Answer (score 0):

> You can't access the request directly from inside a TypeORM entity

Reference and Answer could be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62322885/7349648